# MaterializeCSS SideNav справа на сайте, как?

Tags: css, вёрстка, materialize-css

У фреймворка *MaterializeCSS* есть отличное решение `SideNav` - это панель, которая появляется при нажатии на кнопку. Вот ссылка на демо: [Пример на официальном сайте](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html).
Хочу ее использовать в своем проекте, только мне нужно, чтобы она появлялась справа.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать? Возможно, есть аналоги такой панели справа?

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li><div class="userView">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="images/office.jpg">
      </div>
      <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
      <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
    </div></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

JS

```
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
      menuWidth: 300, // Default is 300
      edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
      closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
      draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
    }
  );
```